# Fredholm integral equation of 2. order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

I want to determine the solution of the Fredholm integral equation $$\int_0^1x\xi u(\xi )\, d\xi -u(x)=x , \ 0\leq x\leq 1$$

We have the equation $$u(x)=-x+\int_0^1x\xi u(\xi )\, d\xi \Rightarrow -x+x\int_0^1\xi u(\xi )\, d\xi$$ This is an equation of second order, correct?

But how can we solve that equation? Could you give me a hint?

I tried to differentiate this given equation to get an ivp, but at the end I got the initial equation.

How could I start?

Answer (score 1):

$$u(x)=-x+x\int_0^1\xi u(\xi )\, d\xi$$
$\int_0^1\xi u(\xi )\, d\xi$ is a definite integral with constant bounds. Thus it is a constant, say $C$. It is not any constant insofar $u(x)$ is not any function but is the sought function solution of the integral equation.
$$\int_0^1\xi u(\xi )\, d\xi=C$$
At this step the value of $C$ is still unknown. We will determine it so that the integral equation be satisfied :
$$u(x)=-x+x\,C$$
$$u(x)=(C-1)x$$
$$C=\int_0^1\xi u(\xi )\, d\xi=\int_0^1\xi(C-1)\xi\, d\xi=(C-1)\int_0^1\xi^2\, d\xi=\frac{C-1}{2}$$
$$C==\frac{C-1}{2}$$
$$C=-1$$
$$u(x)=-x+x(-1)=-2x$$